# Rails Exception in Controller executes querying instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, activerecord, controllers

In my Rails 3.0.11 app, we have very simple code in a controller:

```
def index
  @record = Record.valid # scope around 80,000 records
  asdfasdfsa # consider this is a typo to raise NameError Exception
end
```

The interesting thing is that when it came to the typo, the app seems to query/execute the @record instance variable first before raising an exception. The query costs almost 1 min to get records. So in browser, the page hanges for a long while before coming into an exception template.

If I replace @record with a local variable "record", the querying doesn't happen at all. Anyone knows what it is going on?

Comment: what does it mean 'a normal variable "record"'?

Comment: I should have called it local variable, like instead of having @record = Record.valid, we assign record = Record.valid

Comment: Are you using some kind of exception notification gem? If there is no typo, and no exception raised, it should still hang for a long while, or does it hang longer when an exception is raised? (assuming your view does something with `@record` and the data is retrieved in the normal case).

Comment: I think the original questioner was surprised that a delayed query would still be executed after an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my blog post [Ruby's Inspect Considered Harmful](http://devblog.agworld.com.au/post/24392662859/rubys-inspect-considered-harmful) for details about this very issue. In short, though:

1. NameError calls `inspect` when formatting its error message
2. The default implementation of `inspect` calls `inspect` on all instance variables *recursively*
3. NameError *throws away* the result of `inspect` if it is *longer than 65 characters*
4. For us, this meant that a typo in a View caused Rails to hang *for 20 minutes* while Ruby built a huge, 20MB string and then proceeded to *throw it away*
5. It took us *7 months* to get a [trivial fix for this into Rails core](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525)

In short, I consider the behaviour of NameError to be a heinous bug within the Ruby interpreter. I can think of no sane reason for this implementation.

Comment: Direct link to the monkypatch fix: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1525#issuecomment-2693127

Comment: Strange behaviour of `inspect`, `$1` listed by `Kernel#global_variables`, no backtraces for `SystemStackError`, slow bugfixes. Seems like MRI just sucks...

Answer (score 4):

As @Khronos points out, it's due to the error message and evaluating the variable, but it's not to_s, it's `#inspect`.

in `actiondispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostic.erb` it calls `<%=h @exception.message %>` to display the error.  A quick jaunt into irb provided this tidbit:

```
class Object ; def inspect; "foo" ; end ; end
 => nil 
a=Exception.new(Object)
 => #<Exception: #<Exception:0x10d8a4108>> 
a.message
 => foo
```

So I think @exception.message will call inspect on the exception, which in turn probably calls inspect on the controller.  While it enumerates the entire object during inspect it runs the query, but when it runs to_s I think it drops all that for just the object id.

I'm still a bit fuzzy, but it does at least have to do with the exception and inspect.

Comment: You're right about #inspect being to blame. I've provided details in my answer; we've wrangled with this issue quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a side effect of the exception handling code.

Think of the behavior you're seeing in your two cases.

1. Instance Variable - 
   You've assigned the query to an instance variable of the controller.  You then throw an exception and as part of that exception handling rails will call to_s on the controller, which then forces the query to execute as by default it shows all the instance variables.
2. Local Variable - 
   You've assigned the query to a local variable of the controller.  When the exception is thrown in this case the local variable is just thrown away.

I find it good practice to always override to_s on objects where creating string representations of the structure could be expensive and/or spammy in the ruby console.

Comment: Can you post some references to the code? Where does this happen?

Comment: I don't know where it happens yet, but add a to_s method to your controller and watch it go faster...

Comment: As @DGM points out to find the actual source gets complicated with all the 'magic' going on.  [link](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) is probably the best place to start.  I usually think of overriding to_s because it's more useful in general and inspect defaults to using it if inspect isn't overridden on the object.